# dynamically allocated memory with garbage characters

Tags: c, pointers, file-handling, memset

While using the following approach to read contents of a file:

```
struct stat st;
stat(argv[i], &st);
int size = st.st_size;

//allocate memory to the whole file size
buffer = malloc(size); 
while (fgets(buffer, size, theFile))
    { //print lines
```

I see that the very first iteration picks some Unicode characters into the char * buffer I have (dynamically allocated). See below:

[image]

contents of the filw:

```
(base) system1@sys% cat 1.txt 
asdas
asd
asd
a
as
das
da
sd
asd
```

**using Clion.**

> Interesting enough these characters appear only for the first argument
> while invoking the function and not with any other argument.
>
> For instance: ./code.c 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
>
> will only add some garbage characters infront of 1.txt right after
> first fgets() is being called.

I can't figure what is causing the buffer to have that. I have tried using memset initialization as well. Any pointers?

Comment: Please tell us more about the context of the problem. What is in the file? What development environment are you using?

Comment: Please show a real [mre] in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, rookie mistake!

```
FILE *theFile = open_the_file(argv[i+1]);
```

fixed it.

I was accessing `argv[i]` which when indexed at 0 refers to the exe file.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Your are coding:

```
struct stat st;
stat(argv[i], &st);
```

But the [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call can fail! Your code should handle that case.

Read about [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) in C.

```
buffer = malloc(size);
```

Notice that [`malloc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) can fail and is likely to *reuse* previously `free`-d memory. When `malloc` succeeds, the memory zone may contain garbage data.

So you should have a test:

```
if (!buffer) { perror("malloc buffer"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

and then clear the buffer (inside your loop!)

```
memset(buffer, 0, size);
```

Read also about [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). It also can fail!

My recommendation: enable more warnings, and debugging info, in your compiler. With the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Once you got no warnings from your compiler, use a debugger (like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) to understand the behavior of your program.

You could be interested in using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code.
And later use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) with the [address sanitizer](https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer) to hunt memory leaks.

Study for inspiration the source code of some [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (or [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), if on Linux; e.g. if your laptop runs [Debian](https://debian.org/)).

Comment: I do have checks for malloc, fgets and file pointers etc in my code.

Comment: Using this to make:

gcc -Wall -Werror -g catfile.c -o catfile